# For which values of h does a solution exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying for a final tomorrow and didn't have this solution in my notes.  Please let me know if this is correct and if not, what I did wrong.

1) For which values of h does a solution exist?
2) For which values is it unique?

\begin{align*}
  x + 2y &= 1\\
-2x + hy &= 3
\end{align*}

So what I did was use an augmented matrix and I come up with:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & h+4/5\end{array}\right]$$

From this I a solution always exists for all h.
Since there are no free variables the solution is unique for all h.

Thanks to anyone looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the augmented matrix:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 &1 \\ 
-2 &h  & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Reduce to:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 &1 \\ 
0 &h+4  & 5
\end{bmatrix}

Setup equations:
$$
    x + 2y = 1   \\
    (h+4)y = 5
$$

h can take any value except the one that makes it go to 0. i.e. not -4

Answer (score 0):

You don't list the steps you took to make your augmented matrix, but somewhere along the line you made a mistake.

Directly translating the system into matrix form gives
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\-2 & h\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}1\\3\end{array}\right].$$

Row-reducing this system is a fine idea, but adding twice the first row to the second does not give the matrix in your question. Instead, you get...

Comment: When I calculate 2(R1)+R2 I come up with {0, h+4, 5} for the second row.  Then I scaled row 2 by 1/h+4.  Ahh....... so I should have {0, 1, 5/h+4}?

Comment: When are you allowed to scale by $\frac{1}{h+4}$?

Comment: I don't know. From your question, I gather the answer may be never?

Comment: Does it work for $h=0$? $h=2$? $h=-4$?